# How can I sum values in column based on the value in another column?

Tags: scripting, text-processing

I have a text file which is:

```
ABC 50
DEF 70
XYZ 20
DEF 100
MNP 60
ABC 30
```

I want an output which sums up individual values and shows them as a result. For example, total of all ABC values in the file are (50 + 30 = 80) and DEF is (100 + 70 = 170). So the output should sum up all unique 1st column names as -

```
ABC 80
DEF 170
XYZ 20
MNP 60
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 19):

```
$ awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
ABC 80
XYZ 20
MNP 60
DEF 170
```

Answer (score 6):

`awk '{sums[$1] += $2} END { for (i in sums) printf("%s %s\n", i, sums[i])}' input_file | sort`

if you don't need the results sorted alphabetically, just drop the `| sort` part.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ perl -lane \
    '$sum{$F[0]} += $F[1];
     END { print "$_ $sum{$_}"
             for sort grep length, keys %sum }' \
    input
ABC 80
DEF 170
MNP 60
XYZ 20
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lane '$_{$F[0]}+=$F[1]}print"$_ $_{$_}"for keys%_;{' file
```

And a little bit less straightforward:

```
perl -ape '$_{$F[0]}+=$F[1]}map$\.="$_ $_{$_}\n",keys%_;{' file
```

Comment: 3 characters shorter: perl -anE '$_{$F[0]}+=$F[1]}say"$_ $_{$_}"for keys%_;{' file

Comment: Can somebody explain for me what ;{ does at the end?

Answer (score 1):

```
my %data;
while (<>) {
    if (my ($key, $value) = /^(\w+) \s* (\d+)$/x) {
        $data{$key} += $value;
    }
}
printf "%s %s\n", $_, $data{$_} for keys %data;
```

Comment: why not split on white spaces instead of  regex?

Comment: Either way would work. My approach is a bit more validating, but also a bit more complex.