# What does a { at the end of a Perl one-liner mean?

Tags: perl

I've seen this one-liner

```
perl -lane '$_{$F[0]}+=$F[1]}print"$_ $_{$_}"for keys%_;{' file
```

here: [How can I sum values in column based on the value in another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311228/sum-up-different-row-values-in-a-file-using-sed-awk-perl)

and I don't remember how the "{" at the end works. 
Could someone explain how it works?

Comment: Perl makes my eyes hurt.

Comment: Just looks like a code-golf solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [Perl help](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

```
-n   assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program
```

This is purely a textual operation, so it gives this program:

```
while (<>) { $_{$F[0]}+=$F[1]}print"$_ $_{$_}"for keys%_;{ }
```

This is an abuse of the `-n` switch because the while loop is closed early due to the unmatched `}` in the original program. But the closing `}` that is added by the `-n` switch still needs to match with something, and that's why there needs to be an extra `{` at the end of the program, even though it doesn't do anything.

In other words, the only reason the last `{` is there is to not give a syntax error.

Comment: Might be nice to mention -MO=Deparse

Comment: We show several examples in _Effective Perl Programming, 2nd Edition_ that use this trick. :)

Comment: A better way to accomplish this (in my opinion) would be to use an `END { }` block.